# How to change vertical size of vertical scrollbar in Android listview

Tags: android, listview, scrollbar

Help please, i'm searching the way to change vertical size of vertical scrollbar in listview (Android). Basically i want to add bottom padding for vertical scrollbar in listview. That means that scrollbar will be drawn not from exact bottom, but with some indent from bottom (40 dp for my purpose).

Comment: Finally I diceded just not to use overlapping view.

Answer (score 1):

Create your vertical scrollbar image with a transparent background and apply a 9patch to achieve this effect. You may have to create density specific images for different densities.

You can learn more about 9-Patch drawables from [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html).

[image: 9 Patch]

Comment: Thanks, but how it helps me to change the lenght of scrolling bar? As I know 9-path drawables is stretchable images supposed to make rounded edged background, and such type of things, but it has not to do with sizes.

Comment: As shown in the image above, since the 9 patch is applied only to the blue stripe (not the transparent area), there will always be space for example (40 pixels) at the top and bottom of the scrollbar and the blue will expand / shrink according to the size of the ListView items.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it tommorow.

Comment: It works, but not in the way I need it. If I add additional space beyond thumb, yes it's drawn with padding from bottom for added space, but it's drawn above the touch point, when I scroll, and also some strange things happen with scroll track, it's drawn reduced length from both sides (maybe it can be fixed with replacing fastScrollTrackDrawable, but still not centered thumb is the problem). And I add space  above and beyond thumb it just reduces overal scrollbar length. (Sorry for my not the best Enlish))

Answer (score 0):

You can change the width of the ScrollBar but I don't know if you can adjust the length since the scollbars are of the length of the ListView.

Comment: Thanks, I know about width, but it doesn't help. I want to change it because I put some semi-transparent views on bottom of the listview and I don't want it to intersects with scrollbar.

Comment: In this case you might try to just hide them using android:scrollbars="none" or setVertical/HorizontalScrollBarEnabled/Disabled() Check documentation here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:scrollbars

Comment: No I need them because it's quite a big list with with fastscroll and sectionindexer. I've found a way to add padding to listview, and it isn't affect on scrollbar, but I need exactly opposite feauture.